# ThreadPoolExecutor : awaiting termination outside the method

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Current scenario :
My code (let say "Class Caller : caller()") is going to call a method of a class (Class ThreadPoolClass : writeData()) which internally executes it's task via ThreadPoolExecutor. Now this implementation doesn't wait for the termination of all of it's tasks.

Issue :
While my code (method caller()) needs to wait until all the tasks from this (method writeData() )ThreadPoolExecutor are finished. Currently the controller comes back to caller() method after submitting the tasks.

ThreadPoolClass's implementation cannot be changed, that's why I wanted to figure out that how can I achieve this.

//Sample code

```
class Caller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadPoolClass t = new ThreadPoolClass();
        t.writeData();

        // I want to wait here until the execution is complete
    }
}

class ThreadPoolClass{
    void writeData() {
        Runnable thread = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //  Do some database commit operations

            }
        };
        ExecutorService fixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        fixedThreadPool.submit(thread);
        fixedThreadPool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Any heads up will be helpful - even whether it is possible or not.

Note** this is just a sample, my original code has a chain of class-method calls which eventually executes the method with ThreadPoolExecutor.

Thanks
Dish

Comment: Would be easier if we could see some actual code. Basically, you could use Futures, Executor.awaitTermination(), just to name two. Can't say if it is possible without changing ThreadPoolClass's Code without seeing it, though.

Comment: I have added the sample code. Please verify the same.

Comment: if you want to wait untill the execution finishes and wont do anything other, is it necessary to use threads?

Comment: I do not see a possibility without changing the ThreadPoolClass's code except to write a new Class doing the same but with the possibility to wait/block or callback.

Comment: Hi @Zavael it is some pre-existing API I am trying to reuse in my application.

Comment: Is it an option to just copy the "Do some database commit operations" and execute them sequentially on the main thread? Reusing code is great but that API makes it impossible as it is.

Comment: Thanks everyone for inputs. So based on above comments and some analysis from my end too I am assuming that this cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for inputs. So based on above comments and some analysis from my end too I am assuming that this cannot be achieved. The summarized comments :

**I do not see a possibility without changing the ThreadPoolClass's code except to write a new Class doing the same but with the possibility to wait/block or callback. –  Fildor**

**Is it an option to just copy the "Do some database commit operations" and execute them sequentially on the main thread? Reusing code is great but that API makes it impossible as it is.**